# Align text with checkbox in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter.checkbutton

I'm trying to align the text with the checkboxes.

[image: test image]

Reading from a list in a text file but only the last checkbox align with the text.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x300") 
root.title("Test")

with open("test.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

checkboxes = []
for line in lines:
    checkboxes.append(tk.IntVar())

for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    c = tk.Checkbutton(root, text=line, variable=checkboxes[i])
    c.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

test.txt:

```
Yellow
Blue
Red
White
Black
Orange
```

Guessing it has something to do with line breaks in the text file. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Apply `.strip()` to each line of text you read from the file, to get rid of the trailing newline character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are trailing newline (`"\n"`) characters at the end of the items except the last one.

You can use `file.read().splitlines()` instead to get rid of those newline characters:

```py
with open("test.txt", "r") as file:
    #lines = file.readlines()
    lines = file.read().splitlines()
```